# Audio analysis in Android

Tags: android, audio, fft, data-analysis

I want to record audio in android and pick up certain frequencies at run-time. A typical example would be a guitar tuner app. 
I use 'Guitartuna' which seems to continuous listen to audio while the app is on and picks up frequencies to tell me if my guitar is tuned or how detuned it is by pointing out a frequency every time I play a string.
Even Google listens continuously for an 'Ok Google' but that's too advanced for me at this stage.
My objective is to pick up the frequencies for now.
I'm an experienced android developer but am totally new to working with audio.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  But subject terms to google include "digital signal processing tutorials", "pitch detection", "pitch estimation", "android real time audio recording", and "android low latency audio".

Answer (score 2):

There is a library made for that called TarsosDSP, check it [here](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP).

The code looks like this:

```
    // create a detector using the FastYin algorithm
    PitchDetector pitchDetector = new FastYin(SAMPLE_FREQ, BUFF_SIZE);
    // ...
    float dataBuffer[] = ...
    float pitch = pitchDetector.getPitch(dataBuffer).getPitch();
```

Thera are also some functions to read and write audio in Android (using the mic and default player).

Comment: Can you please suggest me library for this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59339328/android-audiorecord-with-channel-in-stereo-read-raw-audio-buffer-resulted-in-mix